# How to solve issue "Could not translate expression ...into SQL and could not treat it as a local expression."

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities, linqpad

I have code below:

```
void Main()
{
    var q = from a in Applicants
             where(a.Claims.Any())
             select a.Claims.Sum(c => c.TotalClaimAmount());


    q.Dump();
}

public static class MyExt
{
    public static decimal TotalClaimAmount(this Claim c)
    {
        var t = c.Accommodations.Sum(a => a.AmountClaimed) +
                c.MealAllowances.Sum(ma => ma.AmountClaimed) +
                c.Meals.Sum(m => m.AmountClaimed) +
                c.Mileages.Sum(mi => mi.AmountClaimed) +
                c.Others.Sum(o => o.AmountClaimed) +
                c.ParkingTransits.Sum(pt => pt.AmountClaimed) +
                c.Travels.Sum(tr => tr.AmountClaimed);

        return (decimal)t;
    }
}
```

when I run it in LinqPad get below issue:

InvalidOperationException: Could not translate expression 'a.Claims.Sum(c => c.TotalClaimAmount())' into SQL and could not treat it as a local expression.

Please help me out. Many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no corresponding command for your custom method in SQL. so compiler could not translate your expression. Instead first get your items,then select your results:

```
 var items = Applicants.Where(a => a.Claims.Any()).ToList();
 var results = items.Select(a => a.Claims.Sum(c => c.TotalClaimAmount());
```

Comment: Of course this will run everything on the client, causing the N+1 problem and horrible performance.

Comment: probably.but I don't see another (better) way :)

Answer (score 5):

LINQ is unable to convert the `TotalClaimAmount` method call to a SQL expression.

What you can do, is to extract the expression from the `TotalClaimAmount` method and use it directly in the `Sum` method call.

```
public static class MyExt {
    public static Func<Claim, decimal> TotalClaimAmountFunc = c =>
        c.Accommodations.Sum(a => a.AmountClaimed) +
        c.MealAllowances.Sum(ma => ma.AmountClaimed) +
        c.Meals.Sum(m => m.AmountClaimed) +
        c.Mileages.Sum(mi => mi.AmountClaimed) +
        c.Others.Sum(o => o.AmountClaimed) +
        c.ParkingTransits.Sum(pt => pt.AmountClaimed) +
        c.Travels.Sum(tr => tr.AmountClaimed);

    public static decimal TotalClaimAmount(this Claim c) {
        return TotalClaimAmountFunc(c);
    }
}

void Main() {
    var q = from a in Applicants
         where(a.Claims.Any())
         select a.Claims.Sum(MyExt.TotalClaimAmountFunc);

    q.Dump();
}
```

Comment: Hi Lukas, your code is not working. It got compiling errors. "The name 'TotalClaimAmountFunc' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: I just forget `MyExt`, please see edited answer.

Comment: I suspect you'll need to use Expression<Func<>> instead of Func<>

Comment: Hi Lukas, it still can not pass compiling. The error shows "The name 'TotalClaimAmountExpression' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: Hi Joe Albahari. I am your fans. I love Linqpad very much. I hope oracle Intelligent Prompt can like sql server Intelligent Prompt. That will be very nice. Thank you bring Linqpad to the world.

Comment: Look like I should always try to compile the code ... fixed another typo. `TotalClaimAmount` uses `TotalClaimAmountFunc` not `TotalClaimAmountExpression`.

Comment: Hi Lukas, thanks a lot for your effort. The code pass compile now. It show s another error when run it : "NotSupportedException: Unsupported overload used for query operator 'Sum'."